# Right way to setItem in AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I want to use `AsyncStorage.setItem` inside `AsyncStorage.getItem`. How to do that in right way?

My code is as follows:

```
createVehicle: function (vehicle, cb) {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('vehicle')
    .then(json => {

        let vehicles = [];

        if (json) {
            vehicles = JSON.parse(json);
            let o_vehicle = filter(vehicles, {autralis_id: vehicle.autralis_id});
            if (o_vehicle.length > 0) {
                cb(o_vehicle[0].id);
                return;
            } else {
                vehicles.push(vehicle);
            }
        } else {
            vehicles.push(vehicle);
        }
        AsyncStorage.setItem('vehicle', JSON.stringify(vehicles), () => {
            cb(vehicle.id + 1)
        });
    }).done();
},
```

Is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 10):

I have created a service for Storage which can be used in the entire project as and when required by passing the required params. Have a look :

```
export default {
async setItem(key, value) {
    try {
        return await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    } catch (error) {
        // console.error('AsyncStorage#setItem error: ' + error.message);
    }
},
async getItem(key) {
    return await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
        .then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                try {
                    result = JSON.parse(result);
                } catch (e) {
                    // console.error('AsyncStorage#getItem error deserializing JSON for key: ' + key, e.message);
                }
            }
            return result;
        });
},
async removeItem(key) {
    return await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
}
}
```

This is by far the best practice I have come across till the date. You should use it too.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [official document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#mergeitem), it uses `getItem` inside `setItem`, So I think you could also use `setItem` inside `getItem`, because the return value is just a `Promise` for both `getItem` and `setItem`.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('UID123', JSON.stringify(UID123_object), () => {
  AsyncStorage.mergeItem('UID123', JSON.stringify(UID123_delta), () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('UID123', (err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right way to setItem in AsyncStorage is string data

AsyncStorage accepts and stores only string data, so we must always serialize the data before storing it if it is not a string. This means that we must first convert it to string data before storing it; here, the key and the value are both strings.

// storing data

```
const storeUser = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsynStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(value));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

// getting data

```
const getUser = async () => {
  try {
    const userData = JSON.parse(await AsynStorage.getItem("user"))
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error); 
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I come too late, but I wrote this for myself :

```
import { Base64 } from 'js-base64';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export async function storeItem(key: string, item: string, isJson: boolean) {
    try {
        return new Promise(async resolve => {
            let stringObject = '';
            if (isJson) {
                stringObject = JSON.stringify(item);
            } else {
                stringObject = item.toString();
            }
            let base64Object = await Base64.encode(stringObject);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, base64Object);
            resolve();
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

export async function retrieveItem(key: string, isJson: boolean) {
    try {
        return new Promise(async resolve => {
            let base64Item = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
            if (base64Item === null) {
                resolve(null);
            }
            let item = await Base64.decode(base64Item);
            resolve(isJson ? JSON.parse(item) : item);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

export async function removeItem(key: string) {
    try {
        return new Promise(async resolve => {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
            resolve();
        });
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

I use base64 because of the special characters.

Hope it could helps :)