# How to fix java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have problem regarding on my AsyncStorage.getItem. I have module which is the login, where I need to set the item inside the storage, after I get the result there is an yellow message below that I have Error: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String I didn't know where the error came.

[image: Error]

I will show you guys, my function to set the item in the storage.

```
     if(response.status == '200')
     {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('authorization_code',access_token);
          AsyncStorage.setItem('authorization_expiration',expires_in);
          AsyncStorage.setItem('authorization_type',token_type);

          //let token = AsyncStorage.getItem(JSON.stringify("authorization_code"));
           AsyncStorage.getItem('authorization_code', (err, result) => {
            alert(result);
          });

     }
```

Comment: Java tag removed, doesn't look like Java code. Perhaps you meant Javascript?

Comment: I am getting reverse error as `String` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Double`, what do I am missing here?

Answer (score 9):

Use `toString()` to force type in js side. I suppose that is `expires_in` the floating point number here, so:

```
          AsyncStorage.setItem('authorization_code',access_token);
          AsyncStorage.setItem('authorization_expiration',expires_in.toString());
          AsyncStorage.setItem('authorization_type',token_type);
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695654/right-way-to-setitem-in-asyncstorage

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes for datatype error. once you uses a asyncstorage you must store  only string data types only. if you stores a int it will pass this error. So you can use `.toString()` at the end of the your source code

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', response.data.dataset[0].id.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.toString()`.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("addressId", id.toString())
      .then((success) => {
        console.log("succesfully saved in asyncestorage");
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```